# How to fix error in catalina.out "libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: tomcat, java, port, systemctl

I was getting this error when running `systemctl restart tomcat` in my `$CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out` log file:
https://pastebin.com/Cpfs9xCk

So I followed this post online:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/permission-denied-error-when-binding-a-port-290750651.html

> 5. If using Linux 2.6.24 or later, you can set up a file capability on
>    the java executable, to give elevated privileges to allow opening
>    privileged ports only, and no other superuser privileges:
>
> setcap cap_net_bind_service+ep /path/to/bin/java After setting this you may notice errors when starting Java like this, for example:
>
> $ java -version /path/to/bin/java: error while loading shared
> libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
> directory This means that the library is being imported from a dynamic
> path, and not in the trusted ld.so path. See
> https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7157699 for details. To fix
> this, you need to locate the library, and add its path to the ld.so
> configuration. Note that the below is an example, and this may differ
> depending on Linux distribution. Replace JAVA_HOME with the correct
> location:
>
> $ find JAVA_HOME -name 'libjli.so' JAVA_HOME/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
> echo "JAVA_HOME/lib/amd64/jli" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/java-libjli.conf
> ldconfig -v After setting this all up, you need to make sure that Confluence only starts java with the direct binary path, and not via a
> symbolic link, otherwise the capability will not be picked up.

So I ran this command:
setcap cap_net_bind_service+ep /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64

And I'm getting what it says I might get:

```
 $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64/bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I did what they said to fix it but it's still not working and I'm still getting the above error:

```
$ find $JAVA_HOME -name 'libjli.so'
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
```

I have two of these for some reason. I created this file with the paths, but I'm still getting the error and my tomcat isnt starting.

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/java-libjli.conf
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/jli
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64/lib/amd64/jli
```

Comment: dear Philipp please get the output of netstat - an|grep :80 and lsof |grep :80

Comment: @djdomi neither print anything. nothing is running on port 80 since tomcat isnt starting. I'm not getting that error in the pastebin after I followed the article now I have this different error.

Comment: it seems that not all is showing all as it tells 
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 12 more and there are a other line with 13 more, so please check /var/log/apache*** where *** is the tomcat folder - but confluence wont be easy to run as i remember from my knowledge of projects... i hope you have a strong mental feeling about it :-)

Comment: in case you look for specific files, use apt install apt-file && apt-file update && apt-file search libjli.so

Comment: @djdomi im not getting that error thats in the pastebin. I'm getting the error in $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out posted above, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: $ find JAVA_HOME -name 'libjli.so'
JAVA_HOME/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
 
# echo "JAVA_HOME/lib/amd64/jli" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/java-libjli.conf
# ldconfig -v

Comment: @djdomi I tried that but it's not working. https://pastebin.com/EuH8iVhK

Comment: ok, so now we really need to debug it - # run strace program ## where programm is your executable to see where it awaits the files

Comment: @djdomi When I was trying to debug I noticed my server was hacked and running a crypto miner so I reinstalled CentOS. I decided to setup the server this way as a sysV service, and it's working fine.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

My only issue now is the iptables won't persist port forwarding port 8080 to port 80. I have to run iptables commands at each restart. https://serverfault.com/questions/980681/how-to-forward-port-80-to-another-port-on-the-samemachine-permenatly-on-centos7

Comment: install nginx and configure it as reverse proxy with cache enables, this will speed up

Comment: @djdomi I think I'll do that because I'm also getting this error trying to user certbot  "Please add a virtual host for port 80." nginx might help with it.

Comment: i added for you how to do that with nginx as reverse with caching, you may need to pdate that with your config and i would be glad if you can mark this as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sofar I add the complete way for the nginx part, as the apache-tomcat has been solved by a reinstallation

> mkdir /var/cache/nginx/cache 
>    chown nginx:nginx /var/cache/nginx/cache

Now Edit nginx.conf below the http  section

```
###New cache settings as default
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=hd_cache:10m max_size=10g inactive=2d use_temp_path=off;
proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;
proxy_cache_valid 200 302 3d;
proxy_cache_valid 404      1m;
```

edit /etc/nginx/sites-avaible/yoursite.com

```
#http to https redirect
server {
        server_name yoursite.com *.yoursite.com;
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

#https server
server {
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name yoursite.com *.yoursite.com;

#a special location in case don't cache this file can be deleted
location updater/serversettings.xml {
          expires -1;
          add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        }

                #The root/rest will be redirected
                location / {
                        proxy_cache             hd_cache;
                        proxy_set_header        X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
                        proxy_cache_valid       200 1w;
                        proxy_pass              https://10.10.200.4;
                        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
                        proxy_buffers           16 8m;
                        proxy_buffer_size       2m;
                        gzip on;
                        gzip_vary          on;
                        gzip_comp_level    9;
                        gzip_proxied       any;
}
    #SSL Cert section, as we require ssl, using certbot LetsEncrypt
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yoursite.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yoursite.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Now Enable this site.

> ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-avaible/yoursite.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yoursite.com

and run

> service Nginx reload

This Setup works fine for a WordPress site, I encounter a page speed counter of 95+

Comment: Thanks for all your help nginx is working great. Website loads with TLS even after restart.